# simulate a click action in a phone call in Android

Tags: android

I am a new and developing an android application to solve the following problem.

Sometimes I want to get some information through a call, here is the process.

1. call the number and I will hear the hint voice
2. press 1 to select the language

I wonder if there are library that can be used to simulate a click action during a call, so I can just type in the phone number and then the app will automatically select the language for me.

Answer (score 1):

`View.performClick()` does exist, but the real problem is that you cant interact with that activity (as far as I know).

Comment: Thank you.The interaction is just the problem I want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

may be following link would help you:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/10/how-to-add-hard-wait-and-soft-2-3-sec-pauses-to-your-android-contacts/

Comment: This is cool,thank you!If there exists a library,it will be perfect,because the number I want to press in a call may vary in different situation.

Comment: not sure whether there is any library for this.. I guess its a very small feature and may be you can create one lib for it :-)... I hope it help solve the issue that you were facing..